# A word meaning the opposite action of recruiting

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

If I was starting a club for cool kids only, I would **recruit** all the cool kids by, for example, actively seeking them out and convincing them to join the club.

To keep the uncool kids out of my club, I dissuade them from wanting to be in my club by telling them that it's a dumb club and only losers join.  Is there a word that describes what I'm doing to the uncool kids?

Comment: Ah, rather like the infamous "unvite." Along those lines, I suggest "decruting," although only as a joke, so it's not going in an answer.

Comment: It's called enforced "cool hygiene" - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenics :)

Comment: @JamesMcLeod "decruting" is the term I've been using.  If only it were that easy.

Comment: To slog off would be an alternative in UK slang :p . http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2247646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- frighten off, frighten away, scare away?
- indispose, alienate
- get rid of; shake off

Comment: What the OP is describing isn't really scary or frightening, though.

Comment: There may not be a perfect word, but I am leaning towards alienate, as well.

Comment: Accepting for alienate.

Answer (score 2):

Play down, belittle, minimize, dissuade, soft-pedal, disparage, discourage. I don't think there's a perfect word.

Comment: Yes, I'm beginning to think that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divert):

> **divert**: to turn aside or from a path or course; deflect.

And there is also [discourage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discourage):

> **discourage**: to deprive of courage, hope, or confidence; dishearten; dispirit.

Answer (score 0):

A word that comes to mind is [nobble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nobble) in the senses "to disable" or "to suborn".  Phrase "warn off" might apply.  Also see numerous synonyms of [impede](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impede) and [restrain](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/restrain), such as  throttle, trammel, restrict, baffle, inhibit, encumber, intimidate, [daunt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/daunt), frighten away, frighten off, handicap, and hinder.  Also see [disingenuity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disingenuity).

Answer (score 0):

One time, when America's Phineas T. Barnum had too many people at a show in his tent, he created a sign, "This way to the egress." [exit] A number of people followed it, and found themselves on the outside. So the term I might use is "egressing."

Comment: IF you do it subtly, are you being passive egressive? :D

Answer (score 0):

*Dissuade* would be my choice, seeing as how on the other side you are trying to *persuade* the cool kids.